# how to use keygen.sh API for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

really sorry I am a noob coder trying to make it so users need to have entered a license key that gets stored on the local computer & checks the policy from keygen.sh in python.

so far I have the code below but I am struggling to find any documentation that could help me. I am currently using a libary I found called keygen_licensing_tools but I am unable to figure out how to go about this.

any help would be hugely appreciated

main.py

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
import requests
import json
import hashlib
import os
import sys

from keygen_licensing_tools import check_key
from list1 import type


class MainMenu:
    while True:
        license = check_key(
            "product-name",
            account_id = "",
            keygen_verify_key = "",
            product_id="",
            # cache_path="/tmp/license-cache.json",
            # optionals with default values:
            # refresh_cache_period=timedelta(days=1),
            # cache_age_warning=timedelta(days=3),
            # cache_age_error=timedelta(days=7),
            # expiry_warning=timedelta(days=7),
        )

        if license.is_valid:
            success()

        else:
            print("License Invalid")

        def success():
            print("")
            print("\n Select list:")
            print("[0] - Prices")
            print("[1] - Exit")
            tcg = input("Select (0-1): ")

            if tcg == '0':
                os.system('cls')
                type()
            if tcg == '1':
                print("")
                exit()
```

Comment: https://github.com/keygen-sh/example-python-machine-activation I am also unsure how this function is helpful but that is where the unused imports are from

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I don't have a keygen.sh account nor an API key. So I can't try it myself. So my answer is rather generic but hopefully points you in the right direction.

---

Looks like [`keygen_licensing_tools`](https://libraries.io/pypi/keygen-licensing-tools)' GitHub repo does not exist anymore. Accessing the repo results in a [`404` page](https://github.com/nschloe/keygen_licensing_tools) and is either (temporary?) removed, moved or renamed (as of May 6, 2022).

You are probably better off using the API directly:

- https://keygen.sh/docs/api

You can use (for example) [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make the API calls.

Here is also a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/) how to access an API using `requests`.

You'll first have to authenticate yourself and then you can access the desired endpoint. I am not sure which one that is as I can't lookup what `check_key` is doing.

---

**Edit:** The [link](https://github.com/keygen-sh/example-python-machine-activation) you shared in your comment has a [`main.py`](https://github.com/keygen-sh/example-python-machine-activation/blob/master/main.py) which has two examples of API requests. I don't know if these are those you would need.

I recommend, read up how to use `requests` first (maybe even try another API for testing and understanding the package) and then go through keygen.sh's API to find what you need.